# How to update data of pivot table in Many To Many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a Many To Many relationshp between User Model & Wallet Model.

So at the User.php Model:

```
public function wallets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Wallet::class,'user_wallet','user_id','wallet_id')->withPivot('balance');
    }
```

And at Wallet.php Model:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'user_wallet','wallet_id','user_id');
    }
```

And also the table Migration of `user_wallet` table also goes here:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_wallet', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('usr_id')->on('users');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('wallet_id');
            $table->foreign('wallet_id')->references('id')->on('wallets');
            $table->integer('balance');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

And at the Controller, I added this:

```
$bal = Wallet::with("users")->whereHas('users',function ($query)use($wallet_id,$user_id){
     $query->where('wallet_id',$wallet_id);
     $query->where('user_id',$user_id);
});

dd($bal);
```

But now I need to update `balance` filed of this pivot table which has the same `user_id` and `wallet_id`:

[image]

So how to do this?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `updateExistingPivot`

```
$wallet = Wallet::find($wallet_id);
$wallet->users()->updateExistingPivot($user_id,["balance"=>500]);
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-a-record-on-the-intermediate-table

Answer (score 0):

use something like this:

```
$bal->users()->sync([
    $user_id => [
        'balance' => 1
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::users()